# Using Tilestache for serving maps to iPAD

Tags: tilestache

I am planning to use tilestache as the tile server (map server) for serving maps to both iPAD and web clients.

I plan to generate tiles by Tilemills and store tiles in a Sqlite database (mbtiles) and serve it using Tilestache.

**My questions are:**

**(A)** How scalable is the solution, for example the project may have 200 IPAD users in field?

**(B)** Is client side local caching supported or do we have to pre-load tiles in the local storage?

**(C)** Most important, can any such mobility solution using tilestache be sited to see the performance results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A. I don't think tilestache will have problem with serving 200 users (assuming that they're really just human users, not some bot scraping the server) from MBTiles.

B. Client side caching isn't really determined by the server architecture. So it is possible to use MBTiles (or another caching solution) on the client side, if you want to. See [MapBox IOS Example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-example) for one possibility, which uses both online and offline services.

C. I don't know of any online examples, but it is easy to set up Tilestache, and I think you get realistic test results pretty easily. That will ensure that everything that might contribute to performance is considered (e.g. having to deal with network latency over 3G, the hardware you're using, etc).

Comment: tilecache will work - the server would likely need load-balancing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29 to keep up will with 200 users (if using it at the same time.)

Comment: This is a fair comment, but I don't think 200 users in the field will translate to 200 users getting maps at the same time. Half the users will be off / resting, and traffic will probably be some kind of self-similar pattern. Effective number of concurrent users will likely be something like 5-10, max.

Comment: Thank you user1413799 ,mapperz . I am now going ahead with installation and testing.